# -1 for removed downvoted answer

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Usually If I downvote an answer and it gets removed, the -1 for the downvote get's reversed

[image]

For some reson I got -1 again when an answer I downvoted got removed.

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: The answer must have been so bad that it hurt the calculation algorithm to even touch it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You also [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/943447) on that same post, which got approved and gained you +2 reputation. So that post overall had gained you a net of +1 reputation with the downvote you had cast. Upon deletion, that 1 reputation had to be taken away.

Comment: Believe me the first sentence of this answer is in my draft answer.

Comment: @hims056 As long as you didn't clear the draft, I think a Manager/Dev could confirm that. Otherwise, it didn't happen ;)